# Scrape substring inside text using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have the following text:

```
<script>window.location.replace(\"https:\\/\\/www.facebook.com\\/myuserprofilename\");</script>
```

I need to get the text 'myuserprofilename', but I cannot get the regex right.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: on the server side or client?

Comment: do you use the `nokogiri` gem?

Comment: Nokogiri will only help locate the `<script>` tag and get its text. From that point on it's going to take regular String processing.

Comment: Is the string really `\"https:\\/\\/www.facebook.com\\/myuserprofilename\"` or is it `"https://www.facebook.com/myuserprofilename"`? The first isn't very normal in HTML or JavaScript, but is very normal when a string is inspected in Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string = '<script>window.location.replace(\"https:\\/\\/www.facebook.com\\/myuserprofilename\");</script>'
puts string[/facebook.com\\\/(\w+)/, 1] # => myuserprofilename
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspicious of the URL's format. It really looks like the result of inspecting a string and not like something we'd normally see in HTML or when processing HTML.

With the string cleaned up to how I expect it'd look in the wild, here's how we'd use Nokogiri to parse the HTML, locate the `<script>` tag's contents and then access the last part of the URL's path:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<html><body><script>window.location.replace("https://www.facebook.com/myuserprofilename");</script></body></html>')
url = doc.at('script').text[/\("(.+)"\)/, 1] # => "https://www.facebook.com/myuserprofilename"
File.basename(URI.parse(url).path) # => "myuserprofilename"
```

Using regular expressions to locate the particular `<script>` tag is a lot more error-prone than using a parser like Nokogiri. Once the tag is found, grabbing its contents is easy using `text`, then breaking it down is easy using URI's `path` method. Passing that to `File.basename` results in code that reuses existing well-tested wheels and is more robust as HTML and URLs are too volatile.